# hp webos, pdk plugin defunct in hybrid app.

Tags: webos, mojo, enyo

I have been trying to call a pdk plugin from the mojo hybrid app and have also tried the same with enyo app. In both cases my pdk plugin is shown as , Interesting thing is in case of enyo, i received the plugin_ready response which is sent after the plugin registration is complete.

in the web-os site, they mentioned that it is the issue with pdk plugin that makes it look defunct.

but i could not find a method to resolve it.

This is how my plugin looks,

```
PDL_bool powerCall(PDL_JSParameters *params) {
    runsine();
  char *reply = "Done";
    PDL_JSReply(params, reply);
 return PDL_TRUE; 


}

int main(){
     int result = SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);


    PDL_Init(0);

    PDL_RegisterJSHandler("pawar", powerCall);

    PDL_JSRegistrationComplete();

    PDL_CallJS("ready", NULL, 0); // this is for enyo
    PDL_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
return 0;
}
```

please suggest me how to solve this issue. i know its a very simple task and am frustrated that its taking this long.

Thanks
Shankar

Answer (score 2):

In your plugin you should enter an event loop after you call the "ready" function, and before you call the PDL_Quit() and SDL_Quit(). Not having an event loop causes the plugin process to quit right away.

Here is an example based on the "simple" app that ships with the PDK:

```
int main(){
    int result = SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    PDL_Init(0);
    PDL_RegisterJSHandler("pawar", powerCall);
    PDL_JSRegistrationComplete();
    PDL_CallJS("ready", NULL, 0); // this is for enyo

    atexit(SDL_Quit);
    atexit(PDL_Quit);

    SDL_Event Event;
    bool paused = false;

    while (1) {
        bool gotEvent;
        if (paused) {
            SDL_WaitEvent(&Event);
            gotEvent = true;
        }
        else {
            gotEvent = SDL_PollEvent(&Event);
        }

        while (gotEvent) {
            switch (Event.type) {
                case SDL_ACTIVEEVENT:
                    if (Event.active.state == SDL_APPACTIVE) {
                        paused = !Event.active.gain;
                    }
                    break;

                case SDL_QUIT:
                    // We exit anytime we get a request to quit the app
                    // all shutdown code is registered via atexit() so this is clean.
                    exit(0);
                    break;

                // handle any other events interesting to your plugin here

                default:
                    break;
            }
            gotEvent = SDL_PollEvent(&Event);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```